# Can IT Hit WebDAV Lib be used with ASP.NET Web API 2 in the same Project?

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I´m currently evaluating Web Dav Product for .NET and I´m really impressed. I only noticed that when I´m integrating the sample code (Asp.NetFileSystem) into my existing ASP.NET Web API 2 Project, it doesn´t work with Office Word directly as a save target.
We have Web API 2 with Windows Authentication and CORS Headers on.
Windows Explorer can open and Navigate the WebDAV Folder and I can create new files there. But when I´m saving from word directly, I get errors in Word that the network path does not work / exist. I tried to debug it but it happens
I separated the WebDAV part in it´s own project for test purposes and it works without the problems.

Am I using it wrong in the context of Web API 2, or is this an unsupported usecase?

I´ll try to get fiddler logs to.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Who is "you"? Who are you addressing?

Comment: Sorry for not beeing clear enough. The company providing the library (ITHit) wanted me to create a stack overflow question with a tag for them. Please replace "you" with "ITHit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the IT Hit WebDav we were able to trace the problem down. To work correctly, OPTION requests have to be processed by the WebDAVHandler. We have a custom module which intercepts OPTION requests to handle CORS. Because of our Module, the WebDAVHandler was not able to add the necessary headers, and Office opened the files readonly.